comma, AND and vertical bar operator "|"
This may seem like a stupid question, please bear with me. I wanted to confirm what a comma evaluates to so I did the following.
xy <- c(1:10)
ab <- c(10, 2, 1, 6, 8, 6, 7, 2, 10, 6)

# I ran this knowing the number 3 is absent in `ab`
3 %in% c(xy, ab) # output `TRUE` so I thought it evaluates to an OR

# Ran this
3 %in% c(xy & ab) # output `FALSE` as expected

# then ran this
3 %in% c(xy | ab) # output `FALSE` then I got confused, I was expecting same output as in the comma code

I am thinking the c() function maybe responsible. Can anyone please help me understand?

See ?'|':  "Numeric and complex vectors will be coerced to logical values, with zero being false and all non-zero values being true." So when you run c(xy | ab) it's not dissimilar from 2|5, which evaluates to TRUE, so you are actually asking with 3 %in% c(xy | ab) whether 3 %in% TRUE which is false. In c(xy, ab) you are combining xy and ab, which will take your two 10-element vectors and make one 20 element vector.

@JonSpring, please post that as an answer!

Can you say a little bit more about what you think the | and & operators are doing? Perhaps you think that & is intersect() and | is union() ?

You should run c(xy, ab), c(xy | ab) and c(xy & ab) and see what they return.

@BenBolker I think | evaluates to true if 'any' of the expressions is true while & requires 'all' expressions be true for it to evaluate to true

I think Jon Spring has already explained almost everything in his excellent comment. Your last command:
3 %in% c(xy | ab) # output `FALSE`

returns FALSE and was unexpected to you, I think because you may have incorrectly assumed that the command reads: "Is the number 3 in xy, or is it in ab? This would be written in R code as:
(3 %in% xy) | (3 %in% ab)

which does return TRUE (your expectation).
The issue here is that xy | ab is evaluated first and returns a vector of length 10, all of which are TRUE. Then R determines whether 3 is in that vector, and returns FALSE.
You can combine xy and ab first, using c() with no OR:
## these are equivalent to `3 %in% xy | 3 %in% ab`
3 %in% c(xy, ab)
3 %in% union(xy, ab)

But this only works because what you're doing is checking set membership.

I've tried to edit to union() our answers, and you did beat me to submitting :)

Thanks @GregorThomas - only by 1 few seconds. ;)

Spelling it out more, the reason xy | ab is evaluated as a vector of 10 TRUEs is because | will go through each element of each vector, comparing it to the corresponding element of the other vector, and report TRUE if at least one of the two elements is TRUE. Non-zero numbers will be coerced to TRUE, so xy | ab is equivalent to c(1|10, 2|2, 3|1, ... etc) which is coerced to c(TRUE|TRUE, TRUE|TRUE, TRUE|TRUE ... etc.) which is equivalent to c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE ... etc).
